# Best and Easiest RIA RAD tool?

Tags: rich-internet-application

Can anyone share with me what they think is the best and easiest to learn rapid application development for building Rich Internet Applications? Preferably free but if the one you're suggesting is worth it, I might consider purchasing it if it's **that** easy to use. Thank you to those who'd answer!

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 5):

Try [Wavemaker](http://www.wavemaker.com/), its a nice and easy RAD tool for RIA, the learning curve is not too steep